# Installing SSL certificate on NGINX web server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've created a domain.csr and domain.key with this code:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr
```

Then, using these two I bought a certificate and I got certificate from RapidSSL.

RapidSSL gave me a my_domain.crt. Everything is fine.

However, when I try to install this .crt file, there is a problem.

Documentation says that:

> Concatenate the SSL and Intermediate CA Certificate 
>   using this code:
>
> ```
> cat intermediateCA.crt >> SSL_Certificate.crt
> ```

But I don't have any kind of .crt file in my remote server, and also I don't know which one is mine which I gave: intermediateCA.crt or SSL_Certificate.crt

How can I install this certificate on my web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_domain.crt` is your SSL certificate, and you can download the intermediate certificate from the provider's website [here](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=INFO1548). It's probably [this one](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO28590); you need to copy the text **including** `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, and save it on your server as `intermediate_CA.crt`. The names of the certificate files don't really matter.

Comment: and then how can I use my_domain.crt ?@Glorfindel

Comment: That's [step 3 of the tutorial](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO17664).